# Can I open a bulkhead open to two unfinished spaces with a finished space between?

Tags: code-compliance, utilities

I have crawlspace on two sides of a finished den, with the den sandwiched between them.

Can I finish a bulkhead *through* the den but open to the crawlspace on both sides to simplify utility passage through the finished space?

Comment: Sure it can be built. Only you can know what you can achieve. Do beware of head clearance if the bulkhead extends across a normal walking area.